# How to load/display different embed formType in another one via Ajax depending user choice in addAction()

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, symfony, twig

I'am trying to load differents formType following user choice in a select tag from the main form for an AddAction.

Let me explain you this briefly with this image:
[image]

As you can see, an equipement have one type. and depending on its type, it can be either of the Stockages type or Generators type (sorry for the typo in my schema, I forgot the 's' for Stockages).

> PS: Just know that I have 9 other entities like generators and
>   stockages, I put these two for the example. That's why I need to pass
>   the adding of the specific formType from the choice made in the
>   previous select through Ajax.

Now I have the **main form** for equipement, `EquipementsType.php`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('code')
            ->add('brand')
            ->add('typesequipement', 'entity', array(
                                            'empty_value' => '--select a type of equipements--',
                                            'choices' => '--select a type of equipements--',
                                            'class'    => 'MySpace\MyBundle\Entity\Typesequipement',
                                            'property' => 'nameType',
                                            'multiple' => false,
                                            'mapped' => true,
                                            'label'    => 'choose a type: ',
                                            ))
            ->add('stockages')
            ->add('generators')
        ;
    }
```

I call this main form in my **controller** for the `AddAction()` and I remove the two fields stockages and generators like this:

```
public function addAction() {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $equipements = $em->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:Equipements');

        $equipements = new Equipements;
            $form=$this->createForm(new EquipementsType(), $equipements);
            $form->remove('stockages');
            $form->remove('generateurs');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid())) {

                    $form->bind($request);

                    $em->persist($equipements);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('indexEquipements'));
                } else {
                    return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:addEquipements.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
            }
    }
```

As you can see, in my **main form**, the field typesequipement is a select, and according to the choice of the user in this select, I have to display either the form of *Stockages* (`StockagesType.php`) or the *Generators* form (`GeneratorsType.php`) using **AJAX**.

This is my **Ajax** method in the **same** controller:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/manageequipements/addEquipementsform", name="formAddEquipements")
 * @Method("get")
 */
public function formAddEquipementsAction() {

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $id = '--selectionnez un type d\'équipement--';
        $id = $request->get('id');

            if ($id != '--selectionnez un type d\'équipement--' | $id!='') {

                switch ($id) {
                    //Stockages
                    case '1':
                        $type = $em->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:Stockages');
                        $type = new Stockages;
                            $formTypesEquipement=$this->createForm(new StockagesType(), $type);
                        break;
                    //Generators
                    case '2':
                        $type = $em->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:Generators');
                        $type = new Generators;
                            $formTypesEquipement=$this->createForm(new GeneratorsType(), $type);
                        break;
                }


                $response = new Response();

                $data = json_encode($id); // formater le résultat de la requête en json

                $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                $response->setContent($data);

                return $response;
            }

    } else {

        return new Response('error');
    }
}
```

For now, nothing's working. Indeed, If I choose a value in my select typesequipement, nothing's happened. Of course I am i am aware that my ajax method is not finished, but I am a little lost.

In my twig I have this script for the form, **I used the onChange attribute for the field typesequipement named formTypesEquipement**:

```
 function forTypesEquipement(){
         var id_select = $('#mySpace_myBundle_equipements_typesequipement').val();
         $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('formAddEquipements') }}",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'id': id_select},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json){ // quand la réponse de la requete arrive
              $('#mySpace_myBundle_equipements_typesequipement').html('');
            }
          });
      }
```

Someone know **how to load a form or another for this case using Ajax**, i-e display with Ajax the G`eneratorsTypes.php` if I choose **generators** in my `typesequipement select`, or display `StockagesTypes.php` if I choose the value **stockages** in my `typesequipements select` ?

Comment: Is it necessary to be generated via Ajax? If not, may be you can look up for Form Events - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Comment: @Andariel yes it is necessary to be generated via Ajax. I have to follow the specifications, that's why I have not find a solution yet.

Comment: Okay, then let's say **stockages** and **generators** are hidden by default (not removed). Then based on user's choice you can retrieve all the options for either of the two hidden dropdowns, populate the one you need at the moment and remove its hidden attribute.

Comment: @Andariel I have think about this solution. But here in my question, I put the code for Stockages and Generators. In fact I have 9 other equipements like Stockages, Generators (Electricity, Batteries, Fluids etc etc etc).Each time I have to load and add another formType (like GeneratorsType, StockagesType) to the main form EquipementsType. I don't think it's a good solution to put all the field hidden of all the formType I need to add. What do you think?

Comment: First of all, if all you have in these FormTypes are dropdowns only, I believe you would not need to have new type at all. But anyway, the solution I offered is good enough for 2 or 3 hidden dropdowns.

Comment: That's why I choose to remove the fields of stockages, generators ... etc in my controller for the EquipementsType.php. Because I need to load the specific formType of the equipments chosen in the select typesequipements. Each Time I have to add an equipements, I have to load the specific form depending on the choice made in the previous select tag for typesequipements. Sorry if I am not clear, I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!